# How do I combine object of arrays with the same index?

Tags: javascript

I have this object of arrays:

```
var a = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"};
```

And this one

```
var b = {1: "ONE", 2: "TWO", 4: "four"};
```

And I need to combine the two so the output is like so:

```
var c = {1: "oneONE", 2: "twoTWO", 3:"three", 4: "four"};
```

I'm having lots of trouble to get this to work. Please help!

edit:
Ok, so my simplification of my quesiton didn't make much sense..

I am using Firebase to store data.

```
   var dates = [];
   var ids = [];
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) { //makes raw data array
   var date = childSnapshot.val().date;
   var id = childSnapshot.val().task_id;

   dates.push(date);
   ids.push(id);          
   });

   function cal_list(names, values) { // makes the array read
         var result = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
          if(result[names[i]] === undefined) {
              result[names[i]] = values[i];
          }
          else {
              // How do I add the values[i] to the existing date index?
              // if i used result[names[i]] = values[i] -- it only holds a single date. I need a way to add the value to an existing date.


          }

            };

  var calendar_list = cal_list(dates, ids);
  populateCal(calendar_list); //Successfully populates cal, but i'm missing tasks.
  console.log(result);
```

The console is showing:
`{12-04-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9oFhGluCZsLBXFof8c">Test</a>", 
 12-05-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9PUCxYe2C5gJg7t7gX">Write a blog post</a>", 
 12-06-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9PUCxYe2C5gJg7t7gX">Write a blog post</a>"}`

It is overwriting the indexes, and only storing the last ran value. I need a way to combine the values for like dates, so the end result looks like this:

`{12-04-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9oFhGluCZsLBXFof8c">Test</a><a href="#">SECOND TASK</a><a href="#">THIRD TASK</a>",
 12-05-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9PUCxYe2C5gJg7t7gX">Write a blog post</a>",
 12-06-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9PUCxYe2C5gJg7t7gX">Write a blog post</a>"}`

edit2: The reason I need it to be in this format is because I am using the Calendario JQuery plugin. The data needs to be in a specific format.

edit3: fixed original code.. i think?

Comment: Your arrays are invalid JS.

Comment: What does your combining code look like so far?

Comment: Teemu- thank you for pointing that out. I definitely messed up the terminology. Are these called object arrays?

Comment: For json [] are used for indexed arrays and {} are used for associative arrays. so ['element1','element2','element3'] is good syntax and {"key": "value", "key2": "value2"} is also good syntax. but ["key": "value", "key2": "value2"] is bad syntax. Make sense?

Comment: No, they are called invalid JS : ). Maybe you mean `a = {'1': 'one', ...}`, which actually is an object. Or `[{'1': 'one'}, {'2': 'two'}, ...]`, when you'd have an _array of objects_.

Comment: @Andy - guessing he's demonstrating his logic; he wants the contents of each matching `key`'s `value`s to be concatted. The strings `"three"` and `"THREE"` have different corresponding `key`s.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read the code properly. Long day...

Comment: you should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: You need to decide whether you want an array of separate objects, or one object with a bunch of unique keys.

Comment: Sorry for the syntax errors everyone.. I tried to update the original code to make it proper. I also attempted to clarify my question.. Thanks everyone for trying to help :)
The data needs to be in this format to I can use the calendar jquery plugin: http://tympanus.net/Development/Calendario/js/data.js

Comment: @JordanCoeyman I'm not familiar with "Calendario", but I'm sure any JS plugin is not requiring its data to be delivered with invalid syntax. Also, how `a` and `b` are related to the code you've provided?

Comment: @Teemu - My apologies. I updated my code to reflect the fact I am working with objects not arrays. I hope the syntax is proper now? I have no problems populating the calendar, it's just the fact I can't get multiple tasks to display for a single day. 
A and B aren't related, I was trying to give an example of syntax of what I'm trying to do. The code from my first edit is the exact code.  Look in my "else" statement, thats the code I *think* I'm missing?

Comment: @rab I read it.. I'm still confused as to where I am going wrong. Any more pointers?

Comment: @Andy I want one big object with a bunch of unique keys. I have no problems making this, but how can I concat/add/push a string into a certain key?

Comment: @admdrew You are right.. I'm pretty sure you understand what I'm trying to do. Any tips?

Comment: @JordanCoeyman Hmm... Your code looks like vanilla JS, but still it's using `val()` (from jQuery?). Also this needs some more context, what exactly is `childSnapshot`? I think you've a some kind of lack of logic here too: at first explicitely set `result=[]`, then checking if `result[x]` is `undefined`. Why? `result` is created with no content just before, `result[x]` will be definitely `undefined` in every check, hence the `else` will be never executed...

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/foreach.html 
I am using a forEach statement (from Firebase a nosql) to go through and get my data. 

I am looping through each piece of data from Firebase, and storing the 'date' and the 'task_id' into `var date` and `var id` respectively.  I then am taking these two variables, and trying to run a function that formats them properly. `cal_list`. The reason I check to `result[names[i]] === undefined` was my attempt to stop JS from over-writing the values.

Comment: @Teemu if you look at the last 2 blocks of code (the console output's) in my OP, you can see exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to be able to stuff `<a href="#">SECOND TASK</a>` and `<a href="#">THIRD TASK</a>` inside the value of an existing date

Answer (score 0):

After the long comment thread we've had here, I guess this is what you need:

```
function cal_list(names, values) {
    var result = [], i, n, doubleFound;
    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        /* If you want to avoid double keys (only the first-one will stay):
        for (n = 0; n < result.length; n++) {
            if (names[i] in result[n]) {
                doubleFound = true;
                break;
            }
        if (doubleFound) {
            doubleFound = false;
            continue;
        }
       */
        result[i] = {};
        result[names[i]] = values[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: console: `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 12-04-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9PUJU4uEyzs80zHmqx">Facebook Posts + Engagement</a>", 12-05-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9PUCxYe2C5gJg7t7gX">Write a blog post</a>", 12-06-2013: "<a href="/task/-J9oGrUx_G8vqjJhO95a">Blank Video</a>"]`

I can't seem to get your snip of code to work :/

Comment: : ) Almost there? As I said in my ancient previous comment, it's necessary to know `what exactly is "childSnapshot"`... and what it contains?

Comment: "A DataSnapshot contains data from a Firebase location. Any time you read Firebase data, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot."

"Callbacks receive snapshots of data. A snapshot is a picture of the data at a particular Firebase location at a single point in time. It contains all of the data at that location, including any child data. If you want to convert this data to a native format (such as a JavaScript object on the web or a Dictionary in Objective-C), you must do so explicitly."
https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/
Not sure how to best answer your question :/

Comment: So the childSnapshot is how I am looping through the main DataSnapshot.. Does that make sense? Each date+task combo is stored as a single object in Firebase..

Comment: To me it looks correct logging in the console, except the leading `object`s. I think you'd need to filter out `names[i]` being an object, i.e. `if (typeof names[i] === 'object')  continue;` as a first statement in the `for` loop. This solution assumes `names` are containing strings instead of `Date` objects ofcourse.

Comment: `if (typeof names[i] === 'object') continue;` makes no difference to the output. You are right, the objects in the beginning are incorrect.

Comment: It should!? (When used in `for i` loop.) However, this leads back to `forEach` loop, which is giving wrong data. You could also try to filter the data there, since actually `childSnapshot` already contains those objects. Even better, those objects should be filtered out where `childSnapshot` is defined. Without seeing the full code, it's really hard to advice more. Maybe you could save an example at http://jsfiddle.net ?